# An example of dormant fault?

Tags: terminology, theory, fault

I have been thinking about the dormant fault and cannot figure out an example. By definition, dormant fault is a fault (defect in the code) that does not cause error and thus do not cause a failure. Can anyone give me an example? The only thing that crossed my mind was unusued buggy code..
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dormant faults are much more common than one might think. Most programmers have experienced moments of thinking "What was I thinking? How could that *ever* run correctly?", even though the code didn't show erroneous behaviour. A classic case is faulty corner-case handling, e.g. on failed memory allocation:

```
char *foo = malloc(42);
strcpy( foo, "BarBaz" );
```

The above code will work fine in most situations and pass tests just fine; however, when malloc fails due to memory exhaustion, it will fail miserably. The fault is there, but dormant.

Comment: Great, thanks! Any other example which is not memory related?

Answer (score 2):

Dormant faults are simply ones that don't get revealed until you send the right input [edit: or circumstances] to the system.

A classic example is from [Therac-25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25). The race condition caused by an unlikely set of keys on input didn't occur until technicians became "fluent" with using the system. They memorized the key strokes for common treatments, which means they could enter them very quickly.

Some other ones that come to my mind:

- Y2K bugs were all dormant faults, until the year 2000 came around...
- Photoshop 7 still runs OK on my Windows 7 machine, [yet it thinks my 1TB disks are full](http://www.photoshopgurus.com/forum/photoshop-troubleshooting/39693-error-scratch-disk-full;-how-do-you-fix-problem.html). An explanation is that the datatype used to hold free space was not designed to account for such high amounts of free space, and there's an overflow causing the free space to appear insufficient.
- Transfering a file greater than 32MB with TFTP (the block counter can only go to 65535 in 16 bits) can reveal a dormant bug in a lot of old implementations.

In this last set of examples, one could argue that there was no specification requiring these systems to support such instances, and so they're not really faults. But that gets into completeness of specifications.